# Validation sequence and short-circuitung using @Validated

Tags: java, spring, validation, bean-validation

I have the following bean which I wish to validate:

```
@FieldMatch.List({ @FieldMatch(first = "newPassword", second = "confirmNewPassword", groups=CheckFieldMatchPasswordValidationGroup.class) })
public class ChangePasswordFormModel implements BaseModel<UserEntity>{
    @NotEmpty(groups=CheckEmptyPasswordValidationGroup.class)
    @Length(min = 6, max = 20, groups=CheckLengthPasswordValidationGroup.class)
    private String oldPassword;
    @NotEmpty(groups=CheckEmptyPasswordValidationGroup.class)
    @Length(min = 6, max = 20, groups=CheckLengthPasswordValidationGroup.class)
    private String newPassword;
    @NotEmpty(groups=CheckEmptyPasswordValidationGroup.class)
    @Length(min = 6, max = 20, groups=CheckLengthPasswordValidationGroup.class)
    private String confirmNewPassword;

...
}
```

Firstly, I want to validate the constraints having the marker `CheckEmptyPasswordValidationGroup.class`. If there are errors found, the validation will stop and then go back to the form. If there are no errors, it will continue to the next validation group.

I am using the `@Validated` tag in my controller as follows:

```
public ModelAndView changePassword(
            @ModelAttribute("changePasswordForm") @Validated(
                    {   CheckEmptyPasswordValidationGroup.class,
                        CheckLengthPasswordValidationGroup.class,
                        CheckFieldMatchPasswordValidationGroup.class }) final ChangePasswordFormModel cpfm,
            final BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws Exception {

    final boolean formHasErrors = result.hasErrors();
    // do something here....
}
```

My problem is that, in the above implementation, all the validation groups are executed and all the errors are displayed. I want to retain the use of `@Validated` instead of [calling each validator](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/jsr_303_beans_validation_using). Is it possible to short-circuit the validation instead of having to breakdown my validation steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think such a thing is possible out of the box. What about this utility method?

```
public boolean isValid(ChangePasswordFormModel cpfm, Class<?> ... groups) {
   for(Class<?> c : groups) {
      if(validator.validate(cpfm, c).size() > 0) {
         return false
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: It is a short circut implementation. It validates every group on it's own. After a error in a group was found it's stop the method execution.

Comment: Oops. My bad. I think your solution will work. Although it would be great if I could use the `@Validated` tag and use `GroupSequence`s.

Comment: @mnenego Did you ever find another solution to this which doesn't use the utility method?